# How to kill a job with an infinite loop

Tags: shell-script, kill

I created a shell script named df.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh
while true ; do 
df -hT
sleep 30
done &
```

then I run `./df.sh` (I give execute permission).

After running it, I want to terminate the loop but I can't.

Comment: what is the exact thing that you want to send to background ? the hole `while` ? you want to log it ?

Comment: The whole while

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
$ pkill -f df.sh
```

That will send a termination signal to the script and the script will terminate as soon as the current `sleep 30` call has finished.

Alternatively, use `ps` to find the process ID of the script and send a termination signal to it that way:

```
$ ps

$ kill pid
```

(where `pid` is the integer process ID of the script as listed by `ps`)

Answer (score 0):

First of all if that is you hole script i recommend you to use `&` when you calling the script not at the end of the `while`:

```
./df.sh &
```

I recommend you to use `kill` to send a terminate signal or `kill -9` to send a kill signal if the process doesn't responding after getting the `pid` of the process using `ps` with `grep` or `pgrep`, you can use `pkill`, **but**, careful it will call all `df.sh` processes if you where running more than once, and if you use it with `pkill -f` it will kill any process that match `df.sh` pattern